# How to maintain session between requests in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

We have a nodejs server where we make calls to external system by getting authenticated first from them based on the loggedin user, getting the token and then further calling their data api with the token obtained for secured access. 
What we need is to store the token for one hour right from getting authenticated from external system. So within one hour we dont need to call the authentication api of external system again, since the token given by them has expiry of one hour.

We couldnt get to know how exactly to store and retrieve the token in nodejs. We went through express-session or cookie-session but couldnt achieve what we exactly needed

So our requirement is simple

- Frontend calls nodejs api for the first time where the api makes a api request to the external system and get the token from them to be used for further api calls. Store the token in nodejs layer such that the store flushes out the token in one hour
- Further calls to the external system should take the token stored in nodejs layer
- On flushing of token by store , a new api call can be made to the authentication api to get the token.

Kindly help us here in how to achieve the above behaviour